# How to configure solr1.4 for Distributed Index and distributed search?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to configure distributed search in Solr 1.4. It can work perfectly by using following url "http://localhost:8983/solr/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr,localhost:7574/solr&indent=true&q=ipod+solr"
But i need configure shards in solrconfig.xml. Any idea.........?

Thanks in advance

SENTHIL B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked over the [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) page on the Solr Wiki. This should provide you with a good starting point. And actually, shards are not configured on the solrconfig.xml file as each shard is a separate Solr instance. So you would just need to setup multiple Solr instances, follow the steps in the Distributed Search Example section at the end of the wiki page.